# How do I make macOS ignore the scroll lock key in most places?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I use the Scroll Lock key as push-to-talk because this key is typically not used by any programs on Windows and Linux. I also have my mouse configured to send the Scroll Lock key any time I press one of the side buttons, but it's nice to have it bound to a keyboard key too.

On macOS, when I push the Scroll Lock key, I get a variety of strange behavior in different apps. In Safari, Chrome, and Firefox it does nothing, the Terminal app it types `~`, in iTerm2 it types `;ZQ`, on the desktop it just makes boop noises, and in Finder it highlights the most recently selected file. Discord detects the Scroll Lock key as `UNK71`.

Ideally I would like to configure macOS to ignore the Scroll Lock key in any app except for Discord, so that I can have it be a dedicated push-to-talk key. Is this possible to do?

Comment: How have you configured your mouse to send Scroll Lock? Scroll Lock just doesn't exist on Mac. Key Code 71 is the Clear key, so you might be able to remap using that.

Comment: It's an AmazonBasics gaming mouse. It's configured using Amazon's Windows software, which is saved to the mouse on the hardware level, so once configured I can use it on any computer.

Comment: It's still 'pressing a button' the Mac doesn't know exists [though possibly the same key code as Clear]. Get [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) from the App Store & see what it's actually sending.

Comment: Unicode: 63249 / 0xf711, Keys: F14, Key Code: 107 / 0x6b, Modifiers: 8388864 / 0x800100.

Comment: F14 - that might be possible, at least it's a recognised key. idk how you would persuade all other apps to ignore it, though. Maybe [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org)
 might be able to. It's not an app I use so idk how flexible it is.